# Unstable behaviour of has_key shelve method

Tags: python, shelve

I've been using the shelve library from python (not in a multiprocessing environment), and I've been observing an unstable behaviour when using the has_key() method. Sometimes it returns True and sometimes False, when I know that the key exists in the shelve. What could be the usual cause of such behaviour?

```
import shelve

some_key = 'not relevant'
s = shelve.open('cache.db')
if s.has_key(some_key):
   var = s[some_key]
   print 'found key', some_key

s.close()
```

Note: Python 2.7, Ubuntu 14.04 in a VM VirtualBox, running in a i7 x86-64bit

Comment: Please provide a fully functional example which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Where does `some_string` and `date` come from? Are you really sure that these vaules are consistent? Try printing out the key when `has_key()` returns `False`. And why are you calling `__str__()`? Just use `str(date)`.

Comment: Pedantic: `has_key` has been deprecated for ages, and is inferior to simple contains checking, `if some_key in s:` is faster, more generic, and continues to work in Python 3. Also, you're stomping the name `tuple` here, which I find worrisome. If the code which created the shelf was blindly stomping on built-ins, any number of things could have gone wrong. The most likely cause of problems would be that you didn't actually store to the shelf, or that you're opening the same shelf independently in two places, one writing, one reading, and the writer isn't `sync`-ing or `close`-ing in time.

Comment: Another possibility: `shelve` has very specific behavior for when it will make an effort to write back data added to it through mutation of shelf values. Read the documentation for the `writeback` parameter and the `sync`/`close` methods; failing to call them could cause issues. In addition, it explicitly disclaims support for concurrent read/write access, so if you're doing that (in one process or in many), data loss is always possible.